# What is an unbounded array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, definition

What is an unbounded array and is there any difference between an unbounded array and a dynamically allocated array? What are the common operations associated with the unbounded array? (like we have pop and push for stack data structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbounded arrays can be (and usually are) statically allocated.

The primary concern when implementing an unbounded array is to provide dynamic-array like freedom to decide the array size during run-time without the performance penalties of run-time memory allocation.

The following excerpt from an **[excellent article on unbounded arrays](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15122-s11/lectures/12-ubarrays.pdf)** explains it succinctly -

> The general implementation strategy is as follows. We maintain an array of a fixed length **`limit`** and an internal index **`size`** which tracks how many elements are actually in the array. When we add a new element we increment **`size`**, when we remove an element we decrement **`size`**. The tricky issue is how to proceed when we are already at the **`limit`** and want to add another element. At that point, we allocate a new array with a larger **`limit`** and copy the elements we already have to the new array.

Notice that during run-time, until `size` exceeds the initial value of `limit` there is no dynamic allocation involved with an unbounded array.

Some **features** (design requirements) of an unbounded array :

- Getting or setting the value at a particular index (constant time)
- Iterating over the elements in order (linear time, good cache performance)
- Inserting or deleting an element at the end of the array (constant amortized time)

Keeping performance in mind, the only additional operations(compared to regular arrays) associated with unbounded arrays are :

- `add_to_end()`
- `delete_from_end()`

to allow modifying the size of the unbounded array.

Operations like `Insert_in_middle()` and `Delete_in_middle()` are NOT provided keep in mind the primary design principle of an unbounded array i.e. performance.

For more details, checkout the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2710844/319204).

<sub>NOTE : Though the question specifically mentions **dynamically allocated arrays**, probably you might also want to checkout [**dynamic arrays**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). A good example of a dynamic-array is the [`C++ std::vector`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28C++%29) itself which addresses several of the same design principles as that of an unbounded array.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a follow up question. Is the excerpt given by you the only way an unbounded array is implemented? Is it the norm or just one of the ways of implementing the properties of the data structure?

Comment: It is the most common way (AFAIK the only way). One needs to ensure that any implementation satisfies ALL the "features" implied by an `unbounded array` like constant access time, linear adjacent allocation of elements in memory. Hence other implementations like linked-lists may not suffice.

Answer (score 2):

A **dynamically allocated** array is a fixed-size array where the size is fixed when the array is created. It is the allocation that is dynamic when the array is created. Once it is created it is fixed.

Note that **dynamically allocated** is different from **dynamic**.

With an **unbounded array**, the size of the array can grow and shrink arbitrarily as you add items to and remove items from the array. An unbounded array often uses dynamically allocated arrays in the background. Essentially creating chunks / pools of memory using dynamically allocated arrays as an efficiency gain instead of continually resizing when a new item is added.

Looking at the code for an unbounded array from the article linked by TheCodeArtist:

```
struct ubarray {
    int limit; /* limit > 0 */
    int size; /* 0 <= size && size <= limit */
    elem[] A; /* \length(A) == limit */
};
```

Note that this array will grow as needed (when limit is reached), and that it is backed by a dynamically allocated array:

```
elem[] A; /* \length(A) == limit */
```

Answer (score 2):

Two different concepts really.
A statically or dynamically defined array is bounded as in the code that uses it needs to know  what the bounds are.
With an unbound array the code needs some way to discover the bounds from the array itself.

e.g

```
sArray = Array[2..10] Of Integer
dArray = Array[x..y] Of Integer

void DoSomethingToArray(Array Of Integer : myArray)
{
   for(int i = myArray.LowerBound; i <= myArray.UpperBound; i++)
   {
      // twiddle with it.
   }
}
```

You could pass sArray or dArray to the function and it would be quite happy.

Lower and UpperBound are an option, While !Stack.Empty, List.Count > 0, an Enumerator, even Sizeof(myArray) / SizeOf(myArrayType) are all possibilities. The important point is that the code being passed the array, doesn't have to know how the array is bound and can take any array of a specific Type.

Setting the bounds of an array is about allocating memory essentially. A function that uses the array, should hopefully only care that it doesn't reference memory that wasn't allocated to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Unbounded Arrays are basically dynamic, but dynamic arrays can be a little different in terms. As you can dynamically bound an array. In simple for unbounded array/list there is no limit, yes you can push/pop enqueue/dequeue or add/delete from any unbounded list or array. Hope my answer clears your question.

```
int userInput = 0;
 Array dynamic_arr = new Array[userinput];//example of dynamic array
List<string> unbounded_arr = new List<string>(); // example of unbounded array
```

Comment: do you mean a dynamic array sets size at compilation or execution while an unbounded array has no limit on the size and can grow indefinitely?

Comment: List<T> = unbound array is always been a hmm for me. List<T>.ToArray() is the way I like to look at it. Array.Remove and Insert being operations you can only fudge.