# Segmentation fault - new and delete have been used. Lots of arrays are being created during runtime (unbounded array)

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement an unbounded array: [What is an unbounded array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510201/what-is-an-unbounded-array/)

More details on this page:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15122-s11/lectures/12-ubarrays.pdf

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class UBArray
{
public:

    int *arr, *arrN, j, *pos; //Initial array is arr. The position of arr is stored in pos. arrN is the new array created when size = limit.
    int size, limit; //size is the current size of the array and limit is the total size available untill a new array is created.

    UBArray()
    {
        size = 0;
        limit = 10;
        arr = new int[10];
        pos = arr;
    }

private:

    void increment()
    {
        // New array arrN is created and then the values in the old arrays is put into the new array.
        // Limit is increased by 10 - this is the extra space the new array contributres.
        // pos which carries the address of the current array now carries the address of the new array.
        // Later when a new array is created its address will be on the heap which is empty. This address is replace the address stored
        // in the arrN. The older array can still be accessed for the array updation process by using the variable pos.

        // IMPORTANT: I had initially tried to delete the older array to space space but while trying to debug the segmentation fault, I have
        // removed it. I will be adding it again once the error has been fixed.

        arrN = new int[size + 10];
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            arrN[j] = pos[j];
        }
        limit = limit + 10;
        pos = arrN;
    }

public:

    void push(int n)
    {
        if (size<limit)
        {
            size++;
            pos[size-1]=n;
        }
        else
        {
            increment();
            push(n);
        }
    }
    int pop()
    {
        int p = pos[size-1];
        size--;
        return p;
    }
};


int main()
{
    UBArray array;
    int num;
    cout << "Enter 36 elements: ";
    for (int k = 0; k<36; k++)
    {
        cin >> num;
        array.push(num);
    }
    cout <<  endl << "The last element is : " << array.pop();
}
```

I have tried to give comments in the code to make it understandable to the reader. I'm copying some of it here:

Initial array is `arr`. The position of arr is stored in `pos`. `arrN` is the new array created when `size` = `limit`.

`size` is the current size of the array and `limit` is the total size available until a new array is created.

New array `arrN` is created and then the values in the old array are put into the new array.

`Limit` is increased by 10 - this is the extra space the new array contributres.

`pos` which carries the address of the current array now carries the address of the new array.

Later when a new array is created its address will be on the heap which is empty. This address is replaced the address of `arrN`. The older array can still be accessed for the array updation process by using the variable `pos` which will be updated by the old values have been copied to the new one.

I get segmentation fault during execution. I have tried to use cout statements to debug the code but it seems really confusing. I could see loops both inside and outside the for loop inside the `increment` method. I'm unable to figure out much. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by jrok, I changed the code and the seg fault is gone. But I'm getting seg fault again at the creation of the 3rd array.

**UPDATE 2** Everything fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead!

Comment: I think what you call *unbounded array* is better known as `std::vector` amongst the C++ community. Is this some homework?  (have a look at the implementation of `std::vector`)

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger (and not just output statements)? Try setting some breakpoints and see what is happening as you step through the code.

Comment: @Prabhu Code is in the pastebin link

Comment: The code is not so much for an array (or vector) as for a *stack*.

Comment: Fyi, `increment()` has a helluva memory leak and severe UB in it. From what I see the member `arrN` is useless. **Enable your compiler warnings**, of which *two* are immediately apparent in `increment()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Initially I had code to free or delete the older memory which was not used anymore but while debugging the segmentation fault, I removed it. I will add it finally.

Comment: @Walter Sorry I didn't get you. Can you tell me what exactly is basic in this case. What exactly should have I spent time on before doing something that made me interested.

Comment: @WhozCraig How do I show all the warnings? Currently I use: `g++ -Wall -c "%f"`

Comment: `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror` would probably add enough paranoia to keep you honest.

Comment: @WhozCraig Again I see no warnings. I used this: g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -c "unboundedarray.cxx"

Comment: @aste123 basic: how pointers work, what `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, and `delete[]` are etc. not so basic: unbounded array. Note that an unbounded array only needs 3 data members (rather than 6): the address of the beginning of the data buffer, the capacity of the buffer, and the actual size (of the part of the buffer used so far). When expanding, you will temporarily need to hold more data in automatic variables (the address and capacity of the new buffer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr = new int(10*sizeof(int));
```

That creates a single `int`, initialized to the value of `10*sizeof(int)`. The loop you wrote right after this statement runs out of bounds and it's cause of segmentation fault.

What you want is the array form of `new`:

```
arr = new int[10]; // note 10 only, new expression knows the size
                   // of the type it allocates
```

Note that when you assign the pointer to the new array to the pointer to the old array you lose the handle to it and create a memory leak:

```
int* arr = new int[10];
int* new_arr = new  int[20];
arr = new_arr;  // original array at arr has leaked
```

You need to `delete[] arr` before you reassign it. Also, I see no use for the third (`pos`) pointer. Not even for `arrN`, for that matter. One will do. Create a local pointer inside `increment` and assign it to `arr` when you're done deallocating the old array.

Finally, what people have been telling you in the comments, unless this is a learning exercise, don't try to reinvent the wheel and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @jrok thank you very much. I tried to delete the older memory space but while debugging the seg fault, I removed it. I will add it. This change in the code works but only until the 3rd array is created. At the creation of the 3rd array, another seg fault occurs. And yes this is just for learning purpose. I will use vector when I need this data structure.

Comment: everything fixed now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

An unbounded array only needs 3 data members (rather than 6): the address of the beginning of the data buffer, the capacity of the buffer, and the actual size (of the part of the buffer used so far). When expanding, you will temporarily need to hold the address of the new buffer in an automatic variable. Also, you should avoid leaking the memory of previous buffers. A simple layout is like this:

```
struct ua
{
  int size,capacity,*buff;                   // 3 data members only
  ua(int n)                                  // constructor: n = initial capacity
  : size(0)                                  //   initially empty
  , capacity(n<0?0:n)                        //   guard against n<0
  , buff(capacity?new int[capacity]:0) {}    //   only allocate if n>0
  ~ua() { delete[] buff; }                   // destructor: note: delete[] 0 is ok
  void empty() const { return size==0; }     // is array empty?
  void push(int x)                           // add another datum at back
  {
    if(size==capacity) {                     //   buffer is full: we must expand
      if(capacity) capacity+=capacity;       //     double capacity
      else capacity=1;                       //     but ensure capacity>0
      int*nbuff=new int[capacity];           //     obtain new buffer
      if(size)
        memcpy(nbuff,buff,size*sizeof(int)); //     copy data from old to new buffer
      delete[] buff;                         //     free memory form old buffer
      buff=nbuff;                            //     set member buff to new buffer
    }
    buff[size++]=x;                          //   write; increment size (post-fix)
  }
  int pop()                                  // ill-defined if empty()
  { return buff[--size]; }                   //   read; decrement size (pre-fix)
  int operator[](int i) const                // ill-defined if i<0 or i>=size
  { return buff[i]; }
  int&operator[](int i)                      // ill-defined if i<0 or i>=size
  { return buff[i]; }

  // you may add more functionality, for example:
  void shrink();                             // reduces capacity to size
  void reserve(int n);                       // extends capacity to n, keeping data
  ua(ua const&other);                        // copy buffered data of other
  void swap(ua&other);                       // swap contents with other (no copying!)
};
```